# Proof that $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{(k+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What’s are the steps to estabilish that $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{(k+1)}$?

Comment: Just add the fractions on the right in the usual way.

Comment: @lulu: And the other way (starting from left)?

Comment: Use partial fractions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k+1-k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Comment: Observe the symmetry of our answers ;) +1

Comment: That’s it, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In General write:

$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{a}{k}+\frac{b}{k+1}$$ and find $a$ and $b$ since the previous Identity is equivalent to $(a+b)k+a=1$ which means $a+b=0$ and $a=1$

In particular $$\frac{1}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k+1-k}{k(k+1)}=\frac{k+1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{k}{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{k\cdot(k+1)}-\frac{k}{k\cdot(k+1)}=\frac{k+1-k}{k\cdot(k+1)}=\frac1{k\cdot(k+1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a rectangle of sides $(k+1)$ horizontally and $k$ vertically; each $1\times 1$ unit square is $\frac1{k(k+1)}$ of the rectangle.

$$\begin{align*}A &= 
\left.
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\square&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\
\square&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\
\square&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare\\
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square
\end{array}\quad\right\}k\\\\
\frac{A}{k(k+1)} &= \square
\end{align*}
$$

Each row, which is a rectangle of $(k+1)\times 1$, is $\frac 1k$ of the rectangle.

$$\frac Ak = \underbrace {
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\square&\square&\square&\square&\square
\end{array}}_{k+1}\\
$$

Each column, which is a rectangle of $1\times k$, is $\frac1{k+1}$ of the rectangle.

$$\frac A{k+1} = 
\left.
\begin{array}{c}
\square\\
\square\\
\square\\
\square
\end{array}\quad\right\}k\\
$$

The difference $\frac 1k - \frac1{k+1}$ is the unit square which is $\frac1{k(k+1)}$ of the rectangle.

$$\left(\frac 1k - \frac1{k+1}\right)A = \square$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$$ $$= \frac{k+1}{k(k+1)} - \frac{k}{k(k+1)}$$
$$ = \frac{k + 1 - k}{k(k+1)}$$ $$ = \frac{k - k + 1}{k(k+1)} $$ $$ = \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$$